# How i can get elements from DB which exists in my local collection?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq-to-sql

here is code

```
var tempEnities =
                _dc.VKEntities.Where(
                    z => enities.Any(x => x.Name==z.Name && x.Type==z.Type)  ).
                    ToList();
```

`enities` is my local collection.

Well ofcourse this code doesnt work because of linq2sql cannt translate Any to sql. 
Haw can i do it right?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
var tempEnities =
                from db in _dc.VKEntities
                join local in enities on new { db.Name, db.Type } 
                equals new {local.Name, local.Type}
                select db;
```

Some thing like this has been asked quite a few times.

Comment: Thanks. Can i do that thing with extension methods syntax?

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to extend, but generally specking i don't see a reason why not.

Comment: Hm...I have the same error "Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator."

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? .NET 4 (EF4) seems to be fine with that kind of queries.